# Does the ^ symbol replace C#'s "ref" in parameter passing in C++/CLI code?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

In C#, passing by reference is:

```
void MyFunction(ref Dog dog)
```

But in C++/CLI code examples I have seen so far, there is no use of `ref` but instead `^` symbol is used:

```
void MyFunction(Dog ^ dog)
```

Is the use of `^` symbol a direct replacement for `ref` when parameter passing? or does it have some other meaning I'm not aware of?

Additional Question: I also see a lot of:

```
Dog ^ myDog = gcnew Dog();
```

It looks like it's used like `*` (pointer) in C++.. Does it work similarly?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the documentation on MSDN?

Comment: Look here.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/quickcppcli.aspx

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If `Dog` is a reference type (`class` in C#) then the C++/CLI equivalent is:

```
void MyFunction(Dog^% dog)
```

If `Dog` is a value type (`struct` in C#) then the C++/CLI equivalent is:

```
void MyFunction(Dog% dog)
```

As a *type decorator*, `^` roughly correlates to `*` in C++, and `%` roughly correlates to `&` in C++.

As a *unary operator*, you typically still need to use `*` in C++/CLI where you use `*` in C++, but you typically need to use `%` in C++/CLI where you use `&` in C++.

Comment: Why the use of `^%` together? What does passing just `^` do?

Comment: @developer : If `Dog` is a reference type, `void MyFunction(Dog^ dog)` in C++/CLI would be equivelent to `void MyFunction(Dog dog)` in C#. The `^` denotes a reference type, the `%` denotes passing by reference (`ref` in C#).

Comment: Ok that makes sense. but what if I were to do `void MyFunction(Dog dog)` in C++/CLI (i.e. skip the use of the `^` and `%` symbols).. what does that mean?

Comment: @developer : You generally wouldn't do that unless `Dog` is a value type; if `Dog` is a value type then `void MyFunction(Dog dog)` has identical semantics in C++/CLI and C#.

Comment: Would I receive a compiler error if I forgot the `^` for a reference type? (I'm no where near compiling yet.. so can't test my question right now)

Comment: @developer : Yes, unless you specifically designed `Dog` to allow for value semantics in C++/CLI. And given that this is all new to you, we can safely assume you haven't. ;-]

Comment: is there a mark for out:
`void MyFunction(out Dog dog)`

Comment: @fantastory : `out` is just passing by reference plus [`OutAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.outattribute.aspx), so if `Dog` is a value type that'd be `void MyFunction([Out] Dog% dog)`, and if a reference type then `void MyFunction([Out] Dog^% dog)`.

Comment: How about enums? Are they considered reference or value types?

Comment: @Scrontch : `System::Enum` is a reference type, but actual enums themselves are value types. When in doubt, there's always [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isvaluetype).

Answer (score 2):

The ^ operator behaves similarly to a pointer in C++/CLI.  The difference is that it's a garbage-collected pointer.  So:

```
Dog ^ mydog = gcnew Dog();
```

is simply saying that we will new using the managed memory (gcnew) and pass the managed pointer back to mydog.

So:

```
void MyFunction(Dog ^ dog)
```

Is actually passing by address, not be reference, but they're *kinda* similar.  If you want to pass by reference in C/C++ you do something like:

```
void MyFunction(Dog &dog);
```

in the function declaration.  I assume it'll be the same for C++/CLI, but I've never tried it.  I try not to use the ref's since it's not always clear that they are.

EDIT: Well, it's not the same, it's % not &, which makes sense they'd have to change that too.  Stupid C++/CLI.

Comment: C++/CLI is an entirely different, standardized language, separate from C++. You shouldn't expect them to be identical. :-P

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN - [`^ (Handle to Object on Managed Heap)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08.aspx):

> Declares a handle to an object on the managed heap.

And:

> The common language runtime maintains a separate heap on which it implements a precise, asynchronous, compacting garbage collection scheme. To work correctly, it must track all storage locations that can point into this heap at runtime. ^ provides a handle through which the garbage collector can track a reference to an object on the managed heap, thereby being able to update it whenever that object is moved.

Comment: hmm.. ok, so a pointer points directly to an address space, but handles do not? But this handle would work similarly since it helps track the actual object on the managed heap? Like if I modified the object in a function (no return being done), the object will be modified after the function has been called?

Answer (score 1):

The "^" symbol indicates that "Dog" is a CLR object, not a traditional C++ object such as "Dog*", which is a pointer to a C++ object Dog.  This means that "Dog ^ dog" has the same meaning as "Dog dog" (not "ref Dog dog") in C#

Comment: Note that it's possible to use CLR types without `^` in C++/CLI. See this article for more info on C++/CLI stack semantics: [C++: The Most Powerful Language for .NET Framework Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379617(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

3 Types in C++/CLI :

1. Handle Type (^):
   Handle contain address of variable but which can be updated by runtime if it has to move variable around to maximize available free memory.
   Example: `Person ^pp = gcnew Person(); // gcnew in C++/CLI is similar to new in C++.`
2. Reference Type (%):
   Reference alias of a variable. % in C++/CLI is Similar to & in C++.
   Example: `int %ri = i;  // ri is reference alias for i.`
            `Person %rPerson = *pp;   // pp from point number 1`
3. Array Type ([]):