# What is the syntax to pass parameters by reference from c# to c++/cli?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the ^ symbol replace C#'s “ref” in parameter passing in C++/CLI code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616599/does-the-symbol-replace-cs-ref-in-parameter-passing-in-c-cli-code)

I have googled it and searched this forum, but there does not seem to be any answer.

If it was from c# to c#, it would be something like `void MyFunction(ref int var)`. When called, parameters are also preceded by ref. If it was from c++ to c++ it would be `void MyFunction(int &var)`. Thanks.

Comment: The OP is right that it is difficult to find the answer to this question.  The link does not ask the same question, and the answer is not obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Declare the C++ method like this:

```
void MyFunction(int% var)
```

If it's a reference type, use both symbols:

```
void MyFunction(String^% var)
```

It's called a [tracking reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8903062a%28VS.80%29.aspx).